# How can i handle Geolocation on Route 53 and Google Bots located all over the world?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I've set up Amazon Route 53 to route traffic to one of our seven web servers based on Geolocation. This setup generally works correctly for regular users. However, I've encountered an issue with Google Bot.

Despite Google Bot making requests from a server physically located in Europe (which is just 4ms away from our European server), it appears to be using IP ranges that are registered in the USA. As a result, Route 53's Geolocation seems to be directing these requests to our US server, rather than the geographically closer European server.

This becomes especially evident when using tools like Google's PageSpeed Insights, which should ideally test from the nearest server for the most accurate results.

Questions:

1. Shouldn't Google Bot, with a physical location in Europe, get a DNS resolution to our European server based on Route 53's geolocation?
2. Have others experienced similar issues with Route 53 and Google
   Bot's geolocation?
3. Given this challenge, would it be more effective to switch from a Geolocation routing policy to an IP-based  solution in Route 53?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can enable latency-based routing in Amazon Route 53. It should resolve the issue with Google EU bots.